What do I have to do to ensure my program will write into the same file every time and date and time can be executed?
I'm trying to protocol my own PC usage at home.
I'm running a startTime.bat in Windows mmc console via policies -> computer config -> windows -> scripts (startup/shutdown) -> startup
startTime.bat:
date /t >> startTime.txt
time /t >> startTime.txt

The script seemed to be working at first, but it seems to be working sporadically only, leaving out days were I clearly know I have started and shutdown my pc.
What do I have to do to ensure my program will write into the same file every time and date and time can be executed?
Do I need to wait for the other programs to be loaded or executable in some way? And if so how do I do that.
Is the way I did it actually able to do it reliably? Or does Windows doing fast boot most of the time in some way hinder the execution of that script?
Would shell:startup location be more reliable? I have had issues there in the past as well with a program that needed soundfiles and couldn't reliably load those, it would randomly fail to.

A better documented and more tested method might be to use the task scheduler to run this I think.

shell:startup serves this use case perfectly fine for me. I use my own .NET app for this.
